# Altium connections not showing

Tags: altium

In Altium I don’t have any connections (ratnest) showing.  They were showing previously, and in the viewer they are ok.  They should be visible after going to view->connections->show all but are not.
This happens on all the boards and workspaces I open.

There are plenty of unconnected SMD that highlight when I mouse over.  The DRC report gives lots of unconnected pins.  The net color doesn't match the background, and a few nets have special color assigned.  All of this seems like the connections should show, but no luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm aware of two common reasons for disappearing connections.

1. Under `View Configurations` (shortcut L), make sure you have the "Show" checkbox ticked for "Default Color for New Nets".

[image]

2. In the `PCB` panel, make sure that "From-To Editor" is **NOT** selected.

[image]

Comment: Another, less likely possibility, is if every net has been set to "hide connections".

Comment: Another possibility is that nets are coloured the same as the background.

Comment: Sure, but both possibilities have been mentioned by the OP.

Comment: The From-To-Editor was the culprit! Once that was changed the nets appear again.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you update the pcb from the schematic, compile both to make sure there are no errors. Also check the component links to make sure your components are linked from schematic to pcb file. Don't open up the PCB file without opening up the project. Make sure all files are in the project.